# Instantiate different versions of same class with changed constructor and "abstract" modifier

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, backwards-compatibility

I am writing a Java program which uses external libraries. I want to write my code so it is compatible with two different versions of one specific library.

The problem is, they changed a class (called `Configuration` in my example) to abstract, added an abstract method and changed the constructor from a no-argument to parameterized constructor. I am not able to influence the external library and I have to work with what I got.

Old class example

```
public class Configuration {

    public Configuration() {
        //Some code...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        //Some code...
    }

}
```

New class example

```
public abstract class Configuration {

    public Configuration(boolean isCool, Map<String, String> entries, Object otherThing) {
        //Some code...
    }

    public abstract int doSomething();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration conf = new MyConfiguration(false, null, new Object());
        //Some code...
    }

}
```

My implementation

```
public class MyConfiguration extends Configuration {
    
    public MyConfiguration(boolean isCool, Map<String, String> entries, Object otherThing) {
        super(isCool, entries, otherThing);
    }
    
    public MyConfiguration() {
        //needs super constructor call!?
    }

    public int doSomething() {
        //Some code...
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int version = 0;
        Configuration conf = version > 2 ? new MyConfiguration(false, null, new Object()) : new MyConfiguration();  
        //Some code...
    }

}
```

[image: IDE error]

The no-argument constructor of my custom class `MyConfiguration` needs to call the constructor of the superclass in order to be compiled. However, the old class does not have a parameterized constructor, so I will run into an error if I do that.

- Are there any tricks how I don't have to call the super constructor?
- Maybe there is a way using reflection to do what I want?

Comment: I would probably create some abstract factory that tries to load (and verify) one implementation, and if that fails, loads the other one, then you create the configuration through that abstract factory. Compilation might be a bigger problem though. Personally, I would rather just require/support a specific version of the library.

Comment: Surely an option. If I dont find a comfy way I will do two different versions each supporting a specific external library version.

Comment: When the old code does `new Configuration()`, it will never touch your `MyConfiguration` class, hence, there is no need for `MyConfiguration` to be compatible to the old version.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a bit odd, as the new class example contains a reference to your `MyConfiguration`.

Generally, you’re better off maintaining two versions of your `MyConfiguration` class or dropping support for the old version of that library. Or, consider not to use a library that makes such drastic changes.

For completeness, there is a hack addressing your literal question. Assuming that the class `Configuration` is not serializable as shown or at least, the old version isn’t, you can utilize a specific Serialization behavior. When a serializable class extends a non-serializable class, deserializing an instance of it will cause the invocation of the superclass’s default constructor.

So, the code utilizing it could look like:

```java
public class MyConfiguration extends Configuration implements Serializable {
    public MyConfiguration(
        boolean isCool, Map<String, String> entries, Object otherThing) {
        super(isCool, entries, otherThing);
        // new version setup
    }
  
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
                                          throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // old version, Configuration's default constructor has been called
    }
  
    public static MyConfiguration create() {
        return new ByteArrayOutputStream() {
            MyConfiguration get() {
                final short numFields = 0;
                try {
                    Configuration.class.getConstructor(); // check for old version
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(this);
                    // using import static java.io.ObjectStreamConstants.*;
                    os.writeShort(STREAM_MAGIC);
                    os.writeShort(STREAM_VERSION);
                    os.write(TC_OBJECT);
                    os.write(TC_CLASSDESC);
                    os.writeUTF(MyConfiguration.class.getName());
                    os.writeLong(ObjectStreamClass.lookup(MyConfiguration.class)
                                                  .getSerialVersionUID());
                    os.write(SC_SERIALIZABLE);
                    os.writeShort(numFields);
                    os.write(TC_ENDBLOCKDATA);
                    os.write(TC_NULL);
                    os.flush();
                    return (MyConfiguration)new ObjectInputStream(
                           new ByteArrayInputStream(buf, 0, count)).readObject();
                }
                catch(NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                    // new version
                    return new MyConfiguration(false, Map.of(), null);
                }
                catch(IOException|ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    throw new AssertionError(ex);
                }
            }
        }.get();
    }

    public int doSomething() {
        //Some code...
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This class can be compiled against the new version. The `create()` method first checks for the presence of the default constructor. When absent, i.e. running with the new version, the new constructor is called. Otherwise, it deserializes an instance with a stream having no data, so after the superclass’s default constructor has been called, the `readObject` may perform the actual setup.

This all requires a lazy verifier that doesn’t care for the incompatible constructors, as long as no-one tries to actually invoke the constructor. As said at the beginning, you’re likely better off with other solutions.